# Android - AutoComplete dropdown

Tags: android, autocomplete, drop-down-menu

My AutoCompleteTextView is showing his dropdown list above him, and not below as usual.
There are any method that force him to show always below?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the drop down height in XML to force to to a certain height:

```
android:dropDownHeight="120dp"
```

You can set the `120dp` to whatever works for you.